# Need help rounding a double number in printf

Tags: c, double

I'am trying to round a number of a multiply sum but I have no luck with it.

I think I'am using the round function wrong. But I can't find anything.

```
int main()
{
    double euro, ats, sum;

    euro = 414;

    ats = 13.760;
    // Umrechnen in Komma
    sum = euro * ats;
    printf("Summe = %f\n", sum, lround(sum));
    return 0;
}
```

My Goal is that the calculation 414 * 13.760 = 5697 rounded.

Comment: `printf("Summe = %.0f\n", sum);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is passing 2 arguments to `printf` and your format expects only 1 (`%f`).

```c
printf("Summe = %f\n", sum, lround(sum));
```

So you could simply (as Eugene said in the comments):

```c
printf("Summe = %.0f\n", sum);
```

In this case you're printing a float rounded to  digits after the decimal point (`.0`).

---

If you really want to use `lround`, notice that it returns a `long` ([some ref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/round)). So, you'd better:

```c
printf("Summe = %ld\n", lround(sum));
```

Or check the math.h `round`, `ceil` or `floor` functions too!